# Adding a text layer in to a specific location

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to do the last touch to my plot; I attempt to add a text up to the blue line I added before. How I can I do it.

```
data("us_contagious_diseases")
str(us_contagious_diseases)
the_disease <- "Measles"
dat <- us_contagious_diseases %>% 
filter(!state%in%c("Hawaii", "Alaska") & disease == the_disease) %>%
mutate(rate = count/population * 10000) %>% 
mutate(state= reorder(state,rate))   

dat %>% ggplot(aes(year,state,fill=rate))+
geom_tile(color = "grey50") +
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
scale_fill_gradientn(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9,"Reds"), trans = 
"sqrt")+
geom_vline(xintercept=1963, col="blue") + 
theme_minimal()+ theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
ggtitle(the_disease) + 
ylab("") + 
xlab("")
```

This is what I am talking about : [image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use `annotate` to add some text ... maybe something like the following

```
library(dslabs)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data("us_contagious_diseases")
str(us_contagious_diseases)
the_disease <- "Measles"
dat <- us_contagious_diseases %>% 
  filter(!state%in%c("Hawaii", "Alaska") & disease == the_disease) %>%
  mutate(rate = count/population * 10000) %>% 
  mutate(state= reorder(state,rate))   

dat %>% ggplot(aes(year,state,fill=rate))+
  geom_tile(color = "grey50") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9,"Reds"), trans = 
                         "sqrt")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=1963, col="blue") + 
  annotate("text", x = 1963, y = 25, label = "Some text") + # that's the new part
  theme_minimal()+ theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle(the_disease) + 
  ylab("") + 
  xlab("")
```

Comment: thank you, but it is not useful because it  
falls under the heading of the table and creates a bad image

Comment: Tables? Headings? I am confused ... ;) ... you could always modify the position or use something else like geom_text/geom_label? Maybe you could provide some more information on what exactely you are planning to do :)

Comment: I have just edited the post :) thats what ı am talking about

Comment: hi, I think your code still produces the old plot. But if I understand your problem correctely, you would like "Vaccine introduced" to be displayed inside the plot ... so why don't you just play with the y-value of annotate?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it, but when I locate it to right location, it falls down under the white part of plot. And it seems to be corrupted.

Comment: @sociolog try adding `+coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` to your plot